# rEFInd: Kernel Parameters in /boot/EFI/bootx64/refind.conf not applying

Tags: boot, arch-linux, kernel, refind

I've never been able to set kernel parameters on my device, even when I was using grub. I've run out of idea's as I've added them to udev as well and used sysctl but nothing seems to work.

~My rEFInd.conf (Arch Linux entry only) is as follows:

```
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
    icon     /EFI/refind/icons/os_arch.png
    volume   "Arch Linux"
    loader   /boot/vmlinuz-linux
    initrd   /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    options  "root=PARTUUID=5028fa50-0079-4c40-b240-abfaf28693ea rw add_efi_memmap rfkill.default_state=1 vt.global_cursor_default=0 quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_priority=3"
    submenuentry "Boot using fallback initramfs" {
        initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
    submenuentry "Boot to terminal" {
        add_options "systemd.unit=multi-user.target"
    }
    disabled
}
```

I have `rfkill.default_state=1` as rfkill hard blocks bluetooth, and `vt.global_cursor_default=0 quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_priority=3` are for quiet boot, I believe I've done this correctly but Im currently lost.

Answer (score 1):

Last line of your menu entry says it is "disabled" which is default in rEFInd. You can find rEFInd related info in the [arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd)